# pubnub Access manager(PAM) grants revoke() is not working?

Tags: publish-subscribe, pubnub

I've enabled PAM on my pubnub account. I have a simple chat application, where I revoked grants on a channel as follows:

```
pubnub.grant(
{
    channels:[channel,channel+'-pnpres'],
    ttl: 2, // 0 for infinite
    read: false, // false to disallow
    write: false, // false to disallow
    manage: false,
},
function (status) {
    // handle state setting response
    console.log(" status = "+status);
    });
});
```

But, I'm still able to continue chat on that channel. Expectation is since, I shouldn't be allowed to publish/subscribe to that channel as I removed read/write/manage grants.

Why is it not happening?

Comment: This sounds like a bug!  That should not happen of course.  If you revoke access to a channel it should work as expected.  There is one special thing that is important to take note of.  The connected device with recently revoked auth key will still have access to receive one last message.  This is so you can send one last message to the device detailing that they have been revoked access.  This way the mobile app is able to tell the user they've been revoked access.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Access Manager and the Secret Key

The issue was resolved in PubNub Support. For current versions of PubNub SDKs (v4x and some of the last releases of 3x - check Feature Matrix and/or changlelogs to verify), when you init PubNub with the secret key, it has *all access* to any/all channels and channel groups without the need for an auth-key and you cannot revoke access on a client that has the secret-key.

Documentation is being updated about this this behavior to be more prominent.